# Get bottom border off active tab using <div> and <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a page that has a tabbed menu at the top.  I'm getting the menu to work just fine. However, the active tab still has a bottom border on it and I'd like that border to go away.

You can see the entirety of my test code [here](https://thimbleprojects.org/soopergenius/365314).

I've found several places with solutions but they all use `<ul>` and `<li>` to make the tabs and I'm locked into use `<div>` and `<a>` tags. The solutions offered for the list tags don't seem to work with the div and anchor implementation.

Basically, my code currently looks like this.
[image]

I need it to look more like this.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `ul` + `li` approach will work just fine with a `div` + `a` markup structure. Most tabbed content systems simply have the tab overlay the larger bottom border so it cannot be seen. Without any HTML or CSS I cannot help point out how you would do that in your particular setup.

Comment: @Quentin I used Thimble here just like I've seen people use jsFiddle or other sites where they dump examples. The link wasn't to my site.

Comment: @AndrewCooper — It is not Stackoverflow. An [mcve] needs to be on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Quentin  Okay. Will do next time. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using `border-bottom` on your `.tab` bar (which will place the border line below your tabs), you can use a pseudo element to position the line underneath your tabs so they cover it with their white background. Here's a live demo.

(I've copied over your code to Stack Overflow and modified it. In the future, please include all code in your question rather than an external resource.)

```css
/* Style the tab */

div.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

/* Style the bottom border */

div.tab::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

div.tab a {
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

div.tab a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */

div.tab a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(30, 18, 197);
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://thimble.mozilla.org/resources/remix/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="tab">
  <a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a>
  <a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a>
  <a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://thimbleprojects.org/soopergenius/365314/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

The easyest way then:

remove from **div.tab{**

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
```

remove from **.tabcontent**

```
border-top: none;
```

add into **.tabcontent**

```
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-top: -1px;
```

and finally add into **div.tab a.active**

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
```

Comment: They do. They have all 4 borders.

Comment: Nope - check again. `.tabcontent { border-top: none; }`

Comment: I'm so sorry. you are totally right. My browser just stop displaying after `border: 1px solid #ccc;`

Answer (score -3):

One trick would be to overlap the tab over the `<div>` below. Set the class for the active tab to be position:absolute (and you'd need to reduce the height of the tab as well, otherwise the side borders will stick down into the div below.) This was a quick and dirty chrome console trick, so test thoroughly within your design.

[image]
[image]